# jQuery selector by classname minus classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery line in a click event of a *p* element:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.Maintheme not:.Document')
```

I would like to get all the next elements with class .Maintheme but not .Document.

To explain myself a little better, this is the html that i have:

```
<div id="DocumentContents">

<p class="Maintheme">ParentTheme1</p>
<p class="Document">Document1</p>
<p class="Maintheme">ParentTheme2</p>
<p class="Subtheme">SubTheme1</p>
<p class="Document">Document1</p>
<p class="Document">Document2</p>
<p class="Document">Document3</p>
<p class="Subtheme">SubTheme2</p>
<p class="Document">Document1</p>
</div>
```

Having this html content i would like that when you click in a p element if there is not subthemes then show documents. Else if there are subthemes with documents below, just show the subthemes, and if you click in a subtheme show the next documents.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to play around...

Comment: If you have a page structure like that, surely it would be a good idea to use the `h1` - `h6` headings?

Comment: can you not just do, `$('.Maintheme','#DocumentContents').each(/*..*/)`

Comment: So when you click a `.Maintheme` you want to only show the next `.Subtheme`, unless there isn't one, in which case you want to show all the next `.Document` until you hit another `.Maintheme` or `.Subtheme`. And if you click a `.Subtheme`, you show all the next `.Document` until a `.Maintheme` or `.Subtheme`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes Patrick, exactly this is my question.

Comment: Jose3d - I think I've got something for you. But if there is more than one `Subtheme` between two `Mainthemes`, I assume you want to show *both* `Subthemes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZSCs3/

```
$('p:not(.Maintheme)').hide();

$('.Maintheme').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    if ($this.next('.Subtheme').length) {
        $this.nextUntil('.Maintheme').filter('.Subtheme').toggle();
    } else {
        $this.nextUntil('.Subtheme,.Maintheme').toggle();
    }
});

$('.Subtheme').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.Subtheme,.Maintheme').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Incredible!... Works great. I didnt know the .filter selector method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.nextAll()`.

```
var $themes = $(this).nextAll('.Maintheme');
```

You have to do some if-statements from there to create the logic you want.

```
if($themes.length){
}
else{
}
```

Anyways, this looks odd to me. You should use a nested list for instance to display such kind of structures.

Ref.: [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `not` syntax quite correct but it's not clear to me exactly what you are asking for so I won't try and correct it for you, just point you at the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). I agree that this looks a bit off anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) jQuery selector is more suitable for your case since the [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) selector will stop gathering the elements with the Maintheme class on the first occurence of p tag styled with Document class. Hence you can use code slice like this:

$(this).not(':.Maintheme').css(hidePtagsWithDocumentclass);